# pandas countif negative using where()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code and output, what I'm trying to get is shown in the "exp" column, as you can see the "countif" column just counts 5 columns, but I want it to only count negative values.

So for example: index 0, `df1[0]` should equal `2`

What am I doing wrong?

Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

a = ['A','B','C','B','C','A','A','B','C','C','A','C','B','A']
b = [2,4,1,1,2,5,-1,2,2,3,4,3,3,3]
c = [-2,4,1,-1,2,5,1,2,2,3,4,3,3,3]
d = [-2,-4,1,-1,2,5,1,2,2,3,4,3,3,3]
exp = [2,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b':b,'c':c,'d':d,'exp':exp}, columns=['b','c','d','exp'])
df1['sumif'] = df1.where(df1<0,0).sum(1)
df1['countif'] = df1.where(df1<0,0).count(1)
df1
# df1.sort_values(['a','countif'], ascending=[True, True])
```

Output

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) working different, it replace `False` values to `0` here by condition (here False are greater of equal `0`), so cannot be used for count:

```
print (df1.iloc[:, :3].where(df1<0,0))
    b  c  d
0   0 -2 -2
1   0  0 -4
2   0  0  0
3   0 -1 -1
4   0  0  0
5   0  0  0
6  -1  0  0
7   0  0  0
8   0  0  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  0  0
11  0  0  0
12  0  0  0
13  0  0  0
```

You need compare first 3 columns for less like `0` and `sum`:

```
df1['exp1'] = (df1.iloc[:, :3] < 0).sum(1)

#If need compare all columns
#df1['exp1'] = (df1 < 0).sum(1)
print (df1)
    b  c  d  exp  exp1
0   2 -2 -2    2     2
1   4  4 -4    1     1
2   1  1  1    0     0
3   1 -1 -1    2     2
4   2  2  2    0     0
5   5  5  5    0     0
6  -1  1  1    1     1
7   2  2  2    0     0
8   2  2  2    0     0
9   3  3  3    0     0
10  4  4  4    0     0
11  3  3  3    0     0
12  3  3  3    0     0
13  3  3  3    0     0
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, didn't realise 'where ' replaces values that don't meet the condition with 0, makes sense!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `where` here, you can simply use [`df.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) with [`df.sum(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [1329]: df1['exp'] = df1.lt(0).sum(1)

In [1330]: df1
Out[1330]: 
    b  c  d  exp
0   2 -2 -2    2
1   4  4 -4    1
2   1  1  1    0
3   1 -1 -1    2
4   2  2  2    0
5   5  5  5    0
6  -1  1  1    1
7   2  2  2    0
8   2  2  2    0
9   3  3  3    0
10  4  4  4    0
11  3  3  3    0
12  3  3  3    0
13  3  3  3    0
```

**EDIT:** As per OP's comment including solution with `iloc` and `.lt`:

```
In [1609]: df1['exp'] = df1.iloc[:, :3].lt(0).sum(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Learnt a new function, didn't realise that could have been used. Is it possible to use df.lt() with iloc in any way? [edited]

Comment: @cookies Yes, you can do this: `df1['exp'] = df1.iloc[:, :3].lt(0).sum(1)`.